# How to avoid async/await deadlock when blocking is required

Tags: entity-framework

I have the following issue that the SingleOrDefaultAsync from EF do not complete.

I added two extra calls evaluating to `a` and `b` which both returns the correct value. But the `test` line is never completing and the method just waits for ever.

Anyone experienced something similar or have some hints on what can cause this.

```
        public async Task<Subscription> FindSubscriptionByIdAsync(Guid subscriptionId)
        {
            //Works
            var a = DbContext.Subscriptions.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == subscriptionId);
            //Works
            var b = DbContext.Subscriptions.Include(s => s.StorageLocations).SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == subscriptionId);

            //No exceptions or anyhting, it just do not continue from this 
            var test =await DbContext.Subscriptions
                .Include(s => s.StorageLocations)
                .SingleOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == subscriptionId);
            //Debugger never gets to this point.
            return test;

        }
```

#### Update

Based on answer/comments I know my root issue is:

```
    public override CloudStorageAccount GetStorageAccount(string tenant, string purpose = null)
    {
        return GetStorageAccountAsync(new Guid(tenant), purpose).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    }
```

and my problem is that the GetStorageAccount is implemented above because of an interface such its not an option to return Task.

Since I own the interface I have updated my interface to return Task though, but what if I could not update my design and was forced to return the none Task version of the object?
What is the proper way of executing the GetStorageAccountAsync() with out doing the deadlock?

Comment: How do you know `a` and `b` are working? You never wait for those calls to complete.

Comment: Using debugger i can inspect that they return the expected value.

Comment: Using the debugger is not the same thing: there will be a significant delay (for a computer) while you look at the values.

Comment: You do know that the a and b are not tasks ?

Comment: Oops, :-) clearly I'm insufficiently caffeinated.

Comment: @pksorensen: `what if I could not update my design`? I have a blog series on [how `async` modifies some OOP designs](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/01/async-oop-0-introduction.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This is the classic ASP.NET await deadlock.](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) You have been calling Wait or Result somewhere. Don't do that.

If you *must* block (which you have indicated) block in a safe way: `Task.Run(anything).Result`. Don't modify all sites where you await. If you miss one you deadlock (potentially non-deterministically at 4AM in the night in production).

In your example the code would be:

```
Task.Run(() => GetStorageAccountAsync(new Guid(tenant), purpose)).Result
```

which is safe.

Comment: Thanks. There is a high chance that this is the root issue of mine.

Comment: Just to clarify for others (since I first had to think a few times over the following expression 'Don't modify all sites where you await.') Dont do ConfigureAwait(false) on all await calls. Correct?

Comment: Yes. If you want to use ConfigureAwait for efficiency reasons or because you are developing a library, that OK,. But don't do it everywhere to avoid deadlocks. You can't afford to miss a single spot or else or app suffers a catastrophic failure in prod.

Comment: I agree. Anyways, thanks for pointing out these things. I updated the topic to be reflect the real issue and answer.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that if I do not force it to return to the same context it works.

```
    public async Task<Subscription> FindSubscriptionByIdAsync(Guid subscriptionId)
    {

        return await DbContext.Subscriptions
            .Include(s => s.StorageLocations)
            .SingleOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == subscriptionId)
            .NotOnCapturedContext();

    }
```

NotOnCapturedContext is the following extension method.

```
namespace System.Threading.Tasks
{
    using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

    public static class TaskExtensions
    {
        public static ConfiguredTaskAwaitable NotOnCapturedContext(this Task task)
        {
            return task.ConfigureAwait(false);
        }

        public static ConfiguredTaskAwaitable<T> NotOnCapturedContext<T>(this Task<T> task)
        {
            return task.ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This removes the problem but it is a fix of the symptom, not a fix for the underlying problem. You will have this issue again and again.

Comment: Ye thanks for bringing it to my attention. The situation was that somewhere else I could not await the execution and had to use GetAwaiter().GetResult() and I now know that in those cases I need to use configureAwait first to insure the deadlock not can happen

Comment: You can safely block in ASP.NET if you don't block under the standard sync context. `Task.Run(anything).Result` is always safe. Don't modify all the sites where you await. Modify the few sites where you block.

Comment: I understand what you said and have updated my design to reflect this. Therse still one small part I do not understand and I have updated the question with the question. What if i am foced to return the result of the task and dont want to do the deadlock? Let me know if its not clear in the question what I am asking.

Comment: I have updated my answer. Note, that by blocking this way you neutralize the benefits that async brings in the entire call sub-tree in the Task.Run call. Since the benefits are often zero anyway in ASP.NET this might not be a problem anyway.

Comment: I know. But if you are contracted by an interface that do not allow to do so, then there is not much to do.

Comment: Yeah, right. I usually recommend to avoid async if there are not any clear benefits. It has an impact on the codebase like cancer.