# Deadlock possibly caused by pagelock with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, deadlock

We've got the following query using LINQ - Entity Framework - SQL:

```
Context.Dossiers
       .Include(x => x.Persons)
            .ThenInclude(x=> x.Address)
       .Include(x => x.Visits)
       .Include(x => x.Questions)
       .Include(x => x.Signatures)
       .Include(x => x.Areas)
       .Include(x => x.Zones)
       .FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == id)
```

After which we update dossier and save changes.

After running a testing client that will spam the api in parallel multiple times for the same request but with different ids; we notice we're getting deadlocks on Persons.

Persons is not reused for dossiers and each dossier has its own unique set of persons. so there's no overlapping values being locked.

After looking at the deadlock graph we notice there is a page lock on "Persons".

From my understanding page lock will lock additional records (even records that are not related to the query.)

So that's probably what's causing our deadlock.

Now my question is: why is sql turning a simple relationship into a page lock and not a row lock? (there's never more then 10-ish person records for each dossier).

And what would be the best course of action here? Turn off escalation and add an index on the foreign key of Persons with page lock disabled? Or what could we possibly be doing wrong?

Thanks in advance for the input.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30841406/how-to-avoid-async-await-deadlock-when-blocking-is-required

This question seems to be ... slightly a duplicate. I claim, at least, that this link is a reference to the same underlying issue.

Comment: A page is always locked when modifying it, you can't disable that. Please upload your full deadlock XML, along with table and index definitions so we can diagnose further. Please also share the query plan via https://brentozar.com/pastetheplan

Comment: @morten Bork, this question is about sql deadlocks. The question you are referencing is talking about async await deadlocks. One is in the database (mine) the other in code (yours). I'm afraid they're not related. Thanks for the reply though

Comment: @Charlieface i'm not near my laptop anymore but i'll get back to you as soon as i can. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There could be a number of issues that trigger this problem. The first obvious one would be to double-check that all related entities have complete and valid FK relationships to one another and these FKs are mapped/interpreted correctly within EF. Another option to consider if this is running in SQL Server would be to look at enabling snapshot isolation allowing SQL Server to rely more-so on row versioning than locks. The biggest consideration for using this is the impact on the Temp DB, so not necessarily something recommended for very large systems especially if there are large bulk operations being run.

When you are updating a Dossier, do you need each and every included related entity? Another common issue when working with EF is finding a balance between satisfying a desire for DNRY (Do Not Repeat Yourself) vs. performance. Often code like this will reside in a Repository method as a GetDossierById()-type method which is called anywhere and everywhere a Dossier is needed, and ends up eager-loading everything because some of those areas, but not all, benefit from having the extra information loaded.  With highly concurrent use systems such as web applications that may have hundreds of people updating data at any given time, it can be a good idea to design it to make updates as atomic as possible. Rather than giving a user a massive page for updating an entire dossier and everything related to it in one go, then calling "Submit" with the entire graph, breaking it up to submit changes through individual operations. I.e. AddPerson, RemovePerson, etc.  The more data that EF, or any ORM needs to load at one time to perform an operation, the more risk there is of running into locking issues when the system comes under load as more rows are "touched" each time, and the operations generally take longer leaving locks in place longer.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Steve. The configuration in entity framework is OK. I double checked that part. In SQL i could see there was no index on the relationship between dossier and person. So i've added that and will check if that does anything to prevent a page lock. We've looked into snapshot isolation aswel but it's a rather large system so snapshot isolation isn't really an option for us.

Comment: Regarding the DNRY vs performance: it's a rather large solution i've been put on and this would cost allot of work to implement. It's an already existent app with no room for that type of changes. As a decent quick fix for that i've added a dossierlocker that will put a lock per unique dossier around each writable dossier operation so it'll prevent deadlocks when working with the same dossier. That will stop deadlocks from happening if it's about the same dossier but i'm afraid that because of the page lock data not related to the dossier beeing edited is beeing locked.

Comment: The index solved it. My guess is that cause the lack of indexes sql could not retrieve the data in a performant way. Causing it to use page locking instead of row locking.
I went through the entire database and put indexes on logical places where you'd expect them. (foreign keys and search fields etc.) And that seems to have resolved the issue.

Comment: Good to hear, yeah when queries cannot find indexes it resorts to table hits so table or page locks. There will probably be some performance improvement as well in areas. I find with EF-based systems I will start with the obvious indexes then run a profiler to catch and report on the most common queries during UAT sessions, then get index suggestions from SQL server based on those results. Indexes do come at a cost so it's generally advisable to target them where they do the most good. Also look at setting up scheduled index maintenance (defragmentation) on the DB.